# Polymorphism is not working in my Java code

Tags: java, class, oop, polymorphism

I'm beginner at Java and trying to learn polymorphism in Java. I tried to do a simple example but my code acts weird. So this is the problem. I'm creating a circle in my main function and its comes from Shape. What I mean is that;

```
Shape sc = new Circle();
```

After that line when I try to access one of the Circle class functions, I cant see that functions in my automatic code completion. What I mean is that;

```
sc.getArea() //is not working
```

If anyone could help me I would be appreciated...

Here is my Circle Class:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    public double radius;

    public Circle() {
        this.radius = 1.0;
    }

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Circle(String color, boolean filled, double radius) {
        super(color, filled);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        double area;
        area = PI * radius * radius;

        return area;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        double perimeter;
        perimeter = (2*radius)*PI;

        return perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A Circle with radius "+this.radius+", which is a subclass of Shape";
    }
}
```

Here is my Shape Class:

```
public class Shape {
    public String color;
    public boolean filled;
    public static final double PI = 3.14;

    public Shape(String color, boolean filled) {
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public Shape(){
        this.color = "Green";
        this.filled = true;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(this.filled){
            return "A Shape with color of " + this.color +" and filled";
        }
        else
            return "A Shape with color of " + this.color +" and not filled";

    }
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
public class ShapeMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(2.0);
        Square square = new Square(2.0);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(2.0,3.0);

        Shape sc = new Circle(2.0);
        Shape ss = new Square(2.0);
        Shape sr = new Rectangle(2.0,3.0);

        // sc.getArea() ... is not working
        //Polymorphisim is not working

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess your problem is not about polymorphism. Before trying to understand polymorphism try to understand what is inheritance, how methods and properties can be inherited. Also, take a look at access modifiers.

Comment: `Shape` doesn't have a `getArea` method, and `sc` is a `Shape`, so why would your IDE suggest a method that is not part of the class?

Answer (score 1):

`Shape` doesn't have a method called `getArea()`, so the compiler doesn't allow you to call that.

To see polymorphism in action one simple way is to define `Shape` `abstract` and add an `abstract getArea()` method to it:

```
public abstract class Shape {
  // ... all the stuff you already have

  public abstract double getArea();
}
```

You can simply leave the rest of your code identical and now you can call `getArea()` on any variable of type `Shape`.

Of course every non-`abstract` class that extends `Shape` now has to provide an actual implementation (i.e. the code) for the `getArea()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You must cast the sc object in order to access the functions of the Circle class:

```java
Shape sc = new Circle();
Circle circle = (Circle) sc;
circle.getArea();
```

Thus, you are working with the same object (you are not instantiating new objects) but represented in different ways: first as a Shape and then as a Circle.

No attribute value will be lost with casts.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Here's what you need to do in your example:
Since the variable is a Shape, you can only ask it to do what a Shape can do.
So, if you want to ask it to getArea, Shape has to have a method getArea.
If you make Shape's getArea method abstract, Java will redirect the call to Circle's getArea.